# Javascript to open one window by window open

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is like below.
There is home page that has one link with url.
On clicking that link, that url should be open in a new window using window.open.
Now clicking that link again, it should not open another new window.
Existing window should pop up.
But if that window is closed, user should be able to open that window again by clicking that link.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example.

You can do on html as well which is more efficient to do.

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow',width=520,height=570); return false;">Click Me!!</a>
```